# Grey out share calendars in Outlook 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

I use Microsoft Outlook (2016) for my calendaring. As well as my own calendar, I load a variety of shared office calendars.

In previous versions of outlook, each loaded calendar was displayed as a tab at the top of the calendar screen. Appointments from the selected tab were shown in full colour, while those from each delselected tab were all shown in the same uniform mute colour. This made it easy to spot events in my calendar because they were the only events not shown in, say, grey. In other words, my calendar used to look roughly like this (all the appointments in my calendar are blue):

[image: muted colour calendar]

In the latest version of outlook, this presentation seems to have changed. Now the shared calendars I open are also shown in full colour (albeit with slightly lowered opacity). Instead of standing out, my personal appointments now blend in to the overall cacophony of colour that is my workplace calendar. My calendar now looks like this:

[image: full colour calendar]

So my question: is there a way to get the latest version of outlook to show all shared calendars in a uniform colour (or otherwise to mute their visual appearance) like the top screenshot above?

Comment: What's the build number of the Outlook you are currently using? Which version do you exactly mean by "previous versions"?

Comment: I tested in my Outlook 2016(16.0.10325.20036), the calendars are by default colorful but I can manually change the color to grey using the step shared by thims. After that, the selected will show full color in overlay view.

Comment: @YukiSun Thanks for confirming the posted solution works. My build number is 16.14.1 (180613) -- I am running outlook on OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Outlook 2016, on the left pane of the Calendar view, under "My Calendars", right-click each of your shared calendars and select **Color -> Grey**.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that already but they still appear in colour.

Comment: Did you try to reset calendar view? Also, you can try to exit Outlook and run it like this: `outlook.exe /cleanviews`.

Comment: As per YukiSun's comment above, this solution is confirmed to work so I am marking it as accepted. I'm not sure why it doesn't work for me. I'm running Outlook on OSX and launching with /cleanviews doesn't seem to work.